# Can the maven updatePolicy be set to never from the command line?

Tags: maven

I would like repeatable results when running maven commands locally, even if somebody else is pushing updates to a snapshot dependency.
To achieve this, I would like to use the updatePolicy of `never`.
This will allow any dependencies that aren't available locally to be downloaded, while any I have installed locally will be used.
The offline flag won't work in this situation, as there may be dependencies that I haven't installed locally which will need to be downloaded from the remote repo.
I don't want to have to modify the pom, as doing this locally with every checkout will be error prone, and I don't want to commit these changes as it will have adverse effects on other developers.
Ideally I'd like to specify this from the command line. The opposite of the -U flag.

I've searched the docs, and so far have not found out how to do this.

Comment: Why not set it in the `settings.xml`? This is not part of your project.

Comment: <repositories> are currently configured in the poms, not the settings.xml, but that would be the preferred way of doing it if I can set this flag outside of the <repositories> tag.

Comment: Repositories should never being defined in pom files...consuming artifacts from a central repository (like Nexus/Artifactory inside a Company) etc. If you trun off updates you might turn that on in the future and your code/build will fail cause the code has been changed in the meantime this is a Job for a CI solution like Jenkins....also this can handled by using a version control where you build your deps locally but I would not recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want repeatable builds you can create a Docker image that can run Maven. Then load all you project files and run Maven build.

This will provide a clean environment for your build every time.

About the changing dependencies, if you work using SNAPSHOT dependencies, you must expect this different results. That is what SNAPSHOT means: "this is under development".

If you (or your team) **control** the SNAPSHOT dependency and there is an error in the build that's a "good" sign, the tests found something to be fixed.

If you (or your team) **don't control** the SNAPSHOT dependency, you would prefer to the last stable release.

Comment: Thanks jordiburgos. My issue is that I may build at 9am, run some test suites at 10am, a snapshot dependency for the test suite may change at 11am. Then when I re-run test suites after 11am, different dependencies are used for that suite, which may give different results.